# Indexing in a gamma tone filter bank

Tags: matlab, filter

I am running a gammatone filter bank, with an order of 80 and finding the frequncy response in Matlab.

I keep encountering the following error and do not know how to fix it:

Index in position 1 is invalid. Array indices must be positive integers or logical values.

Error in gammatone (line 167)
filterCoeffs = gammatone_output(centerFreq, order, fs);

The 3 functions being used are:

centerFreq=ERBSpace(low_freq, high_freq, NChannels, ear_Q_wide, minBW, order);

order=80;

fs=50000;

gammatone_output is the output of my gamma tone filter.

What should I change to fix this error? Thanks!

I have tried using centerFreq=centerFrequencies(filterIdx); but that also did not work

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, please read [ask] and [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). With the given information, it is impossible for someone else to help you solve the issue. Have you tried to debug it yourself by putting a breakpoint at the line where the error occurs and then checking all the variables?